# Why is C# giving me an error when i try to select a username and put it into a string?

Tags: c#

1. I get an error in C# when I was trying to put a username into a string
2. it says Form1 already contains a definition for 'userName'

   ```
   string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
   string EncrFolder = @"c:\Users\{0}\Desktop\Encryption\", userName;
   ```

Comment: The second error looks like you already have a variable named `userName` in your scope.

Comment: The correct syntax is `string EncrFolder = string.Format(@"c:\Users\{0}\Desktop\Encryption\", userName);` or `string EncrFolder = $@"c:\Users\{userName}\Desktop\Encryption\";`

Comment: use `Path.Combine`  - you should just use the special folders.

Comment: You can use environment variable too `string EncrFolder = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop")` or even better `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
`

Comment: userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do it would be:

```
string EncrFolder = $@"c:\Users\{userName}\Desktop\Encryption\";
```

Comment: got rid of the string and used this instead:

        string EncrFolder = $@"c:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\Desktop\Encryption\";

Comment: I don't know how to use stack overflow I tried to +1 and it did -1

Answer (score 5):

The core problem with your code is that you're missing the call to `string.Format`, which is the method that will replace items in the placeholders with the strings in the argument list:

```
string EncrFolder = string.Format(@"c:\Users\{0}\Desktop\Encryption\", userName);
```

A shorthand way to do this is to use an interpolated string, which is a fancy way to call string.Format, by prefixing the string with a `$` and adding the placholders directly in the string:

```
string EncrFolder = $@"c:\Users\{userName}\Desktop\Encryption\";
```

**But there is still a problem here**

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` in a domain environment will be: `Domain\UserName`, which is **not** necessarily part of the path to the desktop directory (the domain is typically not a separate directory, and is often not used at all).

Using your code above, the path returned on my machine is not correct:

```
 "c:\Users\REDMOND\rufusl\Desktop\Encryption\"
```

One way to resolve this is to use `Environment.UserName` instead:

```
string userName = Environment.UserName;
```

But now what if I've moved my `Desktop` directory to a different path? Or what if it's not stored under just the user name (as @madreflection pointed out, sometimes the folder is created as `userName.DOMAIN` when `userName` already exists for a local user by that name)? You're assuming it's under `c:\Users\userName`, but it's possible that the user has reconfigured that to something else.

So, an even better way would be to use the `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` enumeration along with `Environment.GetFolderPath` and `Path.Combine` to get the full path to the `Encryption` directory:

```
var encrFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), 
                              "Encryption");
```

This returns the correct path on my machine:

```
"c:\Users\rufusl\Desktop\Encryption\"
```

Comment: Even if you haven't moved the folder, sometimes the folder is created as `username.DOMAIN` when `username` already exists for a local user by that name.  This is often observed for Administrator accounts. Another reason to use `Environment.GetFolderPath`.

Answer (score 0):

you can check using  $ or String.Format

example:

```
$"c:\Users\{userName}\Desktop\Encryption\";
```

or

```
String.Format("c:\Users\{0}\Desktop\Encryption\", userName);
```